# How do I solve for $t$ and $s$ in $y = x^{-t/s}$?

Tags: exponentiation

I have 
$$y = x^{-t/s}$$

How do I solve for $t$ and $s$ in terms of the other variables?

Comment: It would be useful if you provided what you have tried. That way users can determine the level at which to answer your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the logarithm of both sides of the equation.

$$y = x^{-t/s} \iff \ln y = \ln\Big(x^{-t/s}\Big)$$

Now use a key property of logarithms to extract $-t/s$ from the exponent of $x$: $$\ln(a^b) = b\ln a$$

Comment: So than -t/s = y/(ln(x)) ?

Comment: $-\dfrac ts = \dfrac{\ln y}{\ln x}$

Comment: Oh because I have to take the log from both sides?.. duh ;)

Comment: Exactly! That's right.

Comment: THANK U.  Is ln the same as log?

Comment: Yes, $\log$ is just fine, and any base will do, as long as it's the same base on each side of the equation. I just used the natural log (base $e$).

Comment: Thanks again,  I'll accept in a couple mins when they let me ^_^

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to help!

Comment: @amWhy: Nice feedback ... +1